# Responding with 404 as status code in Webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

My app is dynamically generating pages by reading the URL. For example, it will handle all URLs formatted like this:

```
[url]/word
```

If `/word` is a valid URL then the app will generate a page and return it back. When the app can't find anything useful it should return a 404 page.

How can I do that? More specifically how do I set the status code to 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within your RequestHandler, you can simply call `self.abort(404)` or `webapp2.abort(404)` to set the error status code.

References:

- [`webapp2.RequestHandler.abort()`](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RequestHandler.abort):

  > Raises an `HTTPException`.
  >
  > This stops code execution, leaving the HTTP exception to be handled by
  >   an exception handler.
  >
  > **Parameters:**
  >
  > ```
  > code – HTTP status code (e.g., 404).
  > args – Positional arguments to be passed to the exception class.
  > kwargs – Keyword arguments to be passed to the exception class.
  > ```
- [`webapp2.abort()`](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.abort):

  > Raises an `HTTPException`.
  >
  > **Parameters:**
  >
  > ```
  > code – An integer that represents a valid HTTP status code.
  > args – Positional arguments to instantiate the exception.
  > kwargs – Keyword arguments to instantiate the exception.
  > ```