# Explanation of self.abort() method in RequestHandler python class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a silly question..
Could you link me the documentation about the method self.abort() of an istance of RequestHandler class?

I found it in a script

> self.abort(422, detail="422 Unprocessable Entity",comment="Giorno non esistente")

I need a documentation about it (or a detailed explanation by one of the users) because i have tried to google it but, because of the keyword "abort", i have founded only uncorrelated results.
I searched also in the documentation about RequestHandler class but i didn't found anything of useful

Comment: http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RequestHandler.abort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responding with 404 as status code in Webapp2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460357/responding-with-404-as-status-code-in-webapp2)